# Spring MVC - Updating a view as the domain objects change

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC to develop a web application that runs simulations.

Each simulation ran modifies a bunch of POJOs which are linked through DB-like relationships and it's data is saved on a DB as it changes.

I already managed to get a "Manual Simulation" working. I have a simple GET Mapping to a "Homepage", where the Lists of objects are displayed in a JSP.

Each request to Spring then performs changes in the data (simple calculations followed by `setProperties`'s) and returns a redirect to the "Homepage", which changes the Lists data in a table.

I've implemented an Automatic 'way' of processing all those changes in a loop by creating a new Thread when Spring catches a set request, which then stays looping until a different request is caught, interrupting the Thread.

**Now the problem is:** I haven't found a straightforward way of displaying the data changed in real-time on the "HomePage" I told you about.

I've browsed through the [Spring MVC 3.2 Preview: Adding Long Polling to an Existing Web Application](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/14/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-adding-long-polling-to-an-existing-web-application) but it seems kind of overkill to what I'm trying to achieve..

Does anyone know of a more simple way to do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Simplest way is polling via Ajax (on a timer in JS) to a servlet that returns the info from the db. Not real 'real-time' but close.

Answer (score 0):

you can use new specification JSR-356 `java websocket` ,friend  it's what you are looking for. i have implemented this in one of our project .it is nice api. for mor information goto following link.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm

Comment: From what I can see, that actually seems more overkill than long polling through Spring. I don't actually need a robust implementation at this moment, just something simple that works for demonstration (prototype). Maybe i'll consider that later. Thanks anyway.